# Detect join link Url in BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram-bot

I am working on a Telegram bot and I'm new in BotFramework environment.
I want to let bot users to invite their friends to the bot with a link that has a parameter like users id ( who invited ) . I want to get this invite link and after joining the invited user I want to message him that user you invited joined this bot . 
How can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create message for user that shows after `/send` command. In this message you can add invite link using deep linking.

link can be flowing: https://telegram.me/bot?start=invite_code

[documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking-example)

and ask your users share this link. Other users will be click it and you can collect information about invites by invite_code

Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I found that BotFrameWork apps exactly works same as ASP .NET MVC so for getting solved my problem I had to use `Request.RequestUri.Query` simply and it return me the invite link arguments so I can do whatever I want . 
Again thanks for your help